# RethinkDB, Efficently Limit Results By Field

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I'm trying to limit results for each `user_id` field.

For example, I have a **list of users Ids** and i want to limit `2 friends` per user from the `friends` selection set.

**Table**: users

```
{
  name: String,
  surname: String
}
```

**Table:** friends

```
{
  user_id: ObjectId // refer to user
  friend_id: ObjectId // refer to user
}
```

**Query**

The closest query i could write to achieve this is the following:

```
var userIds = [1,2];

r.map(userIds, function(userId) {
    return r.table('friends').filter(function(friend) {
        return userId.eq(friend('user_id'));
    }).limit(2).coerceTo('array');
});
```

which result:

```
[
 [
   {
    user_id: 1,
    friend_id: 2
   },
   {
    user_id: 1,
    friend_id: 3
   },
  ],

  [
   {
    user_id: 2,
    friend_id: 3
   },
   {
    user_id: 2,
    friend_id: 4
   },
  ]
]
```

am I using the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

That works but will be slow.  If you create an index on the `user_id` field, you can replace the `filter` with `r.table('friends').getAll(userId, {index: 'user_id'})` which will be much faster.